# How do I convert If statement consisting multiple AND, OR into a switch statement?

Tags: java, boolean-expression

I have a piece of code which looks something like this:

```
     String cStatus = getStatus_c();
     String nStatus = getStatus_n(); 

     if (!((cStatus.equals(PEN) && nStatus.equals(ACT))
            || (cStatus.equals(PEN) && nStatus.equals(SUS))
            || (cStatus.equals(PEN) && nStatus.equals(PEN_CAN))
            || (cStatus.equals(ACT) && nStatus.equals(SUS))
            || (cStatus.equals(ACT) && nStatus.equals(PEN_CAN))
            || (cStatus.equals(SUS) && nStatus.equals(ACT))
            || (cStatus.equals(SUS) && nStatus.equals(PEN_CAN))
            || (cStatus.equals(PEN_CAN) && nStatus.equals(ACT))
            || (cStatus.equals(PEN_CAN) && nStatus.equals(CAN)))) 
{
  //Do someting//
}
```

Above code is fulfilling my requirements but I want to change it to some more readable code using anything like switch block etc. I know how switch works but I'm not sure how to covert my existing code.

---

Just for readability, here is a cleaned-up version (`A` is `PEN`, `B` is `ACT`, `C` is `SUS` and `D` is `PEN_CAN`):

```
if (! (    (cStat == A && nStat == B)
        || (cStat == A && nStat == C)
        || (cStat == A && nStat == D)
        || (cStat == B && nStat == C)
        || (cStat == B && nStat == D)
        || (cStat == C && nStat == B)
        || (cStat == C && nStat == D)
        || (cStat == D && nStat == B)
        || (cStat == D && nStat == D)
      )
)
```

Comment: You don't really need a switch to clean it up, your if statement can be cleaned up by reducing redundancy in status checking using properly placed parentheses.

Comment: Can you logically explain what the `boolean` expression represents? Far more easy to understand then... You could create sub-expressions and store them in `boolean` variables, give them **good variable names**. Then your `if`-expression will use those variables and be readable. You also could identify common variables in the expression and create **nested** `if`-expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Above code is fulfilling my requirements but I want to change it to
>   some more readable code using anything like switch block etc.

A mixing of `AND` and `OR` conditional statement cannot be replaced by a **single** switch case.
You could use embedded switch cases (an outer to handle `cStatus` and an inner to handle `nStatus`)  but it will really not give a readable code :

```
boolean isEnabled = true;
switch (cStatus) {

  case PEN:
    switch (nStatus) {
     case ACT:
     case SUS:
     case PEN_CAN:
        isEnabled = false;
    }
    break;
  case ACT:
    switch (cStatus) {
      ...
    }
    break;
}
```

But you could make your code more readable by eliminating the duplication and by grouping conditional statements with the same `cStatus` value for example.
You could also use the `List.contains()` method to check the  `nStatus` value associated to the `cStatus` value.

Here is a snippet :

```
List<String> nStatusValueForcStatutPen = Arrays.asList("ACT", "SUS", "PEN_CAN");
List<String> nStatusValueForcStatutAct = Arrays.asList("SUS", "PEN_CAN");
...
if (!((cStatus.equals(PEN) && nStatusValueForcStatutPen.contains(nStatus))
    || (cStatus.equals(ACT) && nStatusValueForcStatutAct.contains(nStatus))
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you create a diagram to understand clearly the combination of all the conditions.

Firstly you can clearly see that `PAN` is always the `CURRENT_STATUS` thus, you can shorten the first condition.

Secondly there are several two-way ocnditions, where certain states could be both `NEW_STATUS` either `CURRENT_STATUS`. It's easy to be expressed by the second condition.

Lastly, there are 2 straight one-way conditions (`SUS` -> `PEN_CAN` -> `CAN`) expressed by the last condition.

Combine them together:

```
boolean penCondition = CURRENT_STATUS.equals(PEN) && 
    (NEW_STATUS.equals(SUS) || NEW_STATUS.equals(PEN_CAN) || NEW_STATUS.equals(ACT));
boolean twoWayCondition = CURRENT_STATUS.equals(ACT) && (NEW_STATUS.equals(SUS) && NEW_STATUS.equals(PEN_CAN)) || 
    NEW_STATUS.equals(ACT) && (CURRENT_STATUS.equals(SUS) && CURRENT_STATUS.equals(PEN_CAN));
boolean oneWayCondition = (CURRENT_STATUS.equals(SUS) && NEW_STATUS.equals(PEN_CAN)) || 
    (CURRENT_STATUS.equals(PEN_CAN) && NEW_STATUS.equals(CAN));

if !(penCondition || twoWayCondition || oneWayCondition) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have does not require a switch statement.
You might consider using a `Set`

Here is some code:

```
public class Combination
{
    private final String cStatus;
    private final String nStatus;

    public Combination(
        final String cStatusValue,
        final String nStatusValue)
    {
        cStatus = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(cStatusValue);
        nStatus = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(nStatusValue);
    }

    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int returnValue;

        returnValue = cStatus.hashCode() + nStatus.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(final Object object)
    {
        ... implement equals
    }
}   

... during setup
private Set<Combination> goodCombinationSet = new HashSet<Combination>();

... add all good combinations to the goodCombinationSet.


... when testing.

final Combination testCombination = new Combination(cStatus, nStatus);

if (goodCombinationSet.contains(testCombination))
... do something
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StatusChange curCange = new StatusChange(CURRENT_STATUS, NEW_STATUS);

if(!ngChange.contains(curChange)){

......do something.....

}

//New codes

class StatusChange{

  final Status cur;

  final Status nw;

  ..override equals method......

}


Set<StatusChange> ngChange=new HashSet();
(
ngChange.add(new StatusChange(PEN,ACT));
ngChange.add(new StatusChange(ACT,PEN));
.........
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my final code and I think it's much more readable and clean than the earlier version:

> String cStatus = getcStatus();
>    String nStatus = getnStatus();
>
> String transitionString = cStatus + "_" + nStatus;

```
  switch (transitionString) {
     case "PEN_ACT":
        break;
     case "PEN_SUS":
        break;
     case "PEN_PENCAN":
        break;
     case "ACT_SUS":
        break;
     case "ACT_PENCAN":
        break;
     case "SUS_ACT":
        break;
     case "SUS_PENCAN":
        break;
     case "PENCAN_AC":
        break;
     case "PENCAN_CAN":
        break;
     default: {
        //DO SOMETHING 
        //In my case throwing an exception i.e. program will not continue further.
     }
  }
  {
  //DO SOMETHING ELSE
  }
```